# Как реализовать множественное наследование js

Tags: javascript, наследование, prototype, множественное-наследование

Есть два класса `api` и `max` есть один который я хочу наследовать от них `route`.

```
function api () {
    this.run = function () {
        console.log('run');
    }
}

function max() {
    this.sub = function () {
        console.log('sub');
    }
}

function route() {
   // some...
}


route.prototype = new api();
route.prototype = new max();

var r = new route();
r.run();
r.sub();
```

Получаю ошибку, как мне сделать что-бы вызов родительского метода работал?  При этом нужно что-бы метод вызывался так `r.run();` или `r.sub();`

Comment: На самом деле, речь идет о **множественном наследовании**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Множественное наследование в js не предусмотрено.

Но если очень хочется его сымитировать, то надо выбрать один из родительских классов и использовать его как основу для нового, а из второго просто явно перетащить методы.

Обращаю внимание, что связь с прототипом второго класса теряется, т. е. динамическое добавление методов в него не будет отражаться на наследнике. Впрочем, не считаю это проблемой.

Кстати, если уж очень захочется сохранить динамическую связь, то в ES6 есть возможность применить `Proxy`, в котором решать, как обращаться к свойству. Но это уже из области костылей, к тому же, с сомнительной поддержкой.

```
function First(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

First.prototype.someMethod = function () {
  console.log('someMethod from First');
};

function Second(y) {
  this.y = y;
}

Second.prototype.doSmth = function () {
  console.log('doSmth from Second');
};

function Both(x, y) {
  First.call(this, x);
  Second.call(this, y);
}

Both.prototype = Object.create(First.prototype)

for (var key in Second.prototype) {
  Both.prototype[key] = Second.prototype[key];
}

var obj = new Both(3, 4);
obj.someMethod();
obj.doSmth();
console.log(obj.x, obj.y);
```